# How to return time from AnalogClock/DigitalClock in Android

Tags: android, clock

I need to obtain time from my AnalogClock as a String and pass it as argument in a method. Wonder whats the method of AnalogClock to return current Time.

Thank you.

Comment: Mark the correct answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AnalogClock widget doesn't have methods/properties for accessing the time.
You need to create a new Date() object and then apply DateFormat.format method to it.

Comment: Thats just what i did. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

here the you can get it what you want i used it for my application for analog clock in my program you will get that i get the current time in string .
[you can click link for more in analog clock](http://android-vogue.blogspot.com/2011/04/making-second-hand-working-in-android.html)